# Multiple Custom Admin URL

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

im trying to have the same backend but with multiple subdomains. first i created one of my subdomains in the backend has showen in this image above.
[image]

And is working fine, but not i need the same backend with another subdomain for example "sync.mydomain.com", but i cant find any information on magento docs in configuring custom admin url in multiple domains. Does someone have any idea if it is possible to configure it on magento?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make magento work with multiple domains, you need to make few steps.

1. System->Manage Stores -> Create Store Fill in the store fields,
   taking care that the Website and Root Category are the same as your
   primary site.store. Save Store
2. Create Store View Fill in the store view fields, change Store to the
   new store you just created, give your store view a Name (spaces ok),
   a code and make sure it’s enabled, after that save the store view.
3. System->Configuration->Web Change the scope on the upper left to your newly created store view
   Change Unsecure->Base URL to your second domain (You’ll have to uncheck Use Website)
   Change Secure->Base URL to your second domain (You’ll have to uncheck Use Website)
   Save Config
4. Open the .htaccess at the root of your Magento install
   Add the following, obviously changing the values with your own:

   SetEnvIf Host www.mysecondarydomain.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=yoursecondarystoreviewcode
   SetEnvIf Host ^mysecondarydomain.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=yoursecondarystoreviewcode
5. Clear the cache and re-index the site.

Here is the article for more information:

http://madproject.com/programming/magento-one-site-multiple-domains/

Comment: But in this case is having different domains frontend. What i want is having multiple subdomains with same Administration.

Comment: The steps will be the same.